# scrollToIndex is not working in RTL FlatList React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, scrolltoindex

I have Horizontal FlatList & now I changed phone language to Arabic (RTL). scrollToIndex() is not working in RTL, without RTL it's working fine as expected. Any suggestions?

FlatList

```
<FlatList
    style={myStyles.flatListStyle}
    horizontal={true}
    data={this.props.dataForFlatList}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()} />
```

renderItem function on Press() am passing item id

```
this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({ animated: true, index: id }); // Working fine without RTL - NOT WORKING WITH RTL
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cloud you please provide a demo on e.g. https://snack.expo.io/?

Answer (score 3):

Found this solution.

```
flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({
          index: I18nManager.isRTL && Platform.OS === "ios" ? list.length - 1 - index : index,
        });
```

For some reason ios scrolls to the opposite value in RTL localization.
That is, when choosing the latter to the first. When choosing the penultimate to the second and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are scrolling outside of the render window you need to specifying the `getItemLayout` props

Comment: I am clicking on item Inside FlatList, not scrolling outside. Please read the question again.

Comment: Could you provide updated code with `getItemLayout` ? It should work with`onClick` event

Comment: @Srihari Did you found a solution ?

Comment: No, I guess its issue with FlatList library. Facebook dev team have to fix that.